# How can i parse this data in C# that is coming from a data table

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, numbers, decimal

I have the following C# code that reads in data from a datatable (which was original constructed from an Excel spreadsheet)

```
    private byte GetVal(DataRow dataRow, string caption)
    {
        var val = dataRow.GetValue(caption).ToString().Trim();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            return (byte)(Decimal.Parse(val) * 100);
        }
        return (byte)0;
    }
```

this is blowing up because there is value of: "5.5555555555555552E-2" reading in from one of the cells (the val variable)

its blowing up on this line:

```
    return (byte)(Decimal.Parse(val) * 100);
```

with the error: **Input string was not in a correct format.**

What is the best way to work around this so i can read in the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (byte)(Decimal.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[`Decimal.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx)

**NumberStyles.AllowExponent** (`AllowExponent`is a subset of `NumberStyles.Float`)

> Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The
>   AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string to contain an exponent
>   that begins with the "E" or "e" character and that is followed by an
>   optional positive or negative sign and an integer. In other words, it
>   successfully parses strings in the form nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx.
>   It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or
>   mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the
>   AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags, or use a composite style
>   that includes these individual flags.

Comment: I am now getting that same error when the number is "0.5" . . any suggestions ?

Comment: @Ieora. Edited my answer, but why do you think that it's a byte when there are values with decimal places? Then i would suggest to return `Decimal` or `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (byte)(Decimal.Parse(val, NumberStyles.AllowExponent) * 100);
```